# Cloud Datastore Emulator return 503 'Service Unavailable' when used in Android Test Station

Tags: android, linux, docker, google-cloud-datastore, http-status-code-503

I'm trying to use the [Android Test Station](https://source.android.com/compatibility/tests/development/android-test-station/ats-user-guide). I download [Android Test Station CLI](https://storage.googleapis.com/android-mtt.appspot.com/prod/mtt) and run `./mtt start`, but the UI is not started. Then I run `docker exec -it mtt cat /data/log/server/current` to get the log outside of the docker. Here is the log

```
[2020-08-12 17:34:13 +0800] [721] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8086 (721)
[2020-08-12 17:34:13 +0800] [721] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-08-12 17:34:13 +0800] [736] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 736
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/unicategories_tools/cache.py:37: UserWarning: Unicode unicategories database is outdated. Please reinstall unicategories module to regenerate it.
  'Incompatible unicategories database. '
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8085/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
WARNING:root:/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/cacerts/urlfetch_cacerts.txt missing; without this urlfetch will not be able to validate SSL certificates.
INFO:root:Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING:root:An exception has been encountered when attempting to use Application Default Credentials: File /tmp/keyfile/key.json (pointed by GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable) does not exist!. Falling back on dummy AppIdentityServiceStub.
INFO:root:Starting Cloud Datastore emulator at: http://localhost:8087
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/api_server.py", line 502, in _launch
    else 'SCATTERED'))
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/cloud_emulators/cloud_emulator_manager.py", line 123, in Launch
    emulator_cmd=self._cmd, start_options=options, silent=silent)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/cloud_emulators/datastore/datastore_emulator.py", line 134, in __init__
    if not self._WaitForStartup(deadline):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/cloud_emulators/datastore/datastore_emulator.py", line 158, in _WaitForStartup
    response, _ = self._http.request(self._host)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1626, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1368, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1288, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 938, in connect
    self.sock.connect((self.host, self.port) + sa[2:])
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/socks.py", line 415, in connect
    self.__negotiatehttp(destpair[0], destpair[1])
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/socks.py", line 381, in __negotiatehttp
    raise HTTPError((statuscode, statusline[2]))
HTTPError: (503, 'Service Unavailable')

INFO:root:Starting API server at: http://127.0.0.1:8083
INFO:root:Starting gRPC API server at: http://localhost:44289
INFO:root:Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
INFO:root:Saving search indexes
```

It seems that the Cloud Datastore Emulator returns 503 'Service Unavailable'.
But I'm sure that the Cloud Datastore Emulator is running by `top` command.

Add some log in the python script, I get the command that launches the Cloud Datastore Emulator, which is

`'/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/cloud-datastore-emulator/cloud_datastore_emulator', 'start', '--testing', '--regenerate_indexes=false', '--auto_id_policy=SCATTERED', '--port=8007', '--store_on_disk=true', '--store_index_configuration_on_disk=true', '--index_file=/mtt/index.yaml', '--storage_file=/tmp/mtt/datastore.db', '--require_indexes', '/tmp/tmpwvDVWT'`.

Is there something wrong with this command? Could anyone tell why there is a 503 Error?

Answer (score 1):

Update:

I found the reason. I add no_proxy settings in .docker/config.json and it works!
If you have similar problem, just set noProxy to "localhost,127.0.0.1,metadata.google.internal" will solve it.